# comparing the same month values in different years

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
I have the below data frames 
  ----  
    df=
     city    code     qty  month   year
     hyd     1        10    1      2016
     hyd     2        12    2      2016
     hyd     3        15    3      2016
     hyd     1        25    1      2017
     hyd     2        15    2      2017
     hyd     3        25    4      2017
     hyd     1        25    1      2018
     hyd     2        15    3      2018
     hyd     3        25    6      2018

    b = 
     city    code     qty  month   year  
     hyd     1        10    1      2016
     hyd     2        12    2      2016
     hyd     3        18    3      2016
     hyd     4        22    4      2016
     hyd     5        10    5      2016
     hyd     6        12    6      2016
     hyd     1        12    1      2017
     hyd     2        12    2      2017
     hyd     3        16    3      2017
     hyd     4        25    4      2017
     hyd     5        10    5      2017
     hyd     6        14    6      2017
     hyd     1        10    1      2018
     hyd     2        12    2      2018
     hyd     3        18    3      2018
     hyd     4        25    4      2018
     hyd     5        10    5      2018
     hyd     6        12    6      2018
```

I want to compare the df with the b and get their previous year quantity of those months in a single row. The year must compare only with the years less
    than that year. Below is the result data frame.

```
     resultdf=
     city    code     qty  month   year   qty_2016   qty_2017  qty_2018
     hyd     1        10    1      2016
     hyd     2        12    2      2016
     hyd     3        15    3      2016
     hyd     1        25    1      2017       10
     hyd     2        15    2      2017       12
     hyd     3        25    4      2017       22 
     hyd     1        25    1      2018       10        15
     hyd     2        15    3      2018       18        16        
     hyd     3        25    6      2018       12        14
```

Below is the code:

```
attribute_name = 'city'
attribute_code = 'code'
df1 = df[df['year'].isin(['2018'])]
month_list = df1.month.unique()
feature_list = df1[attribute_name].unique()
code_list = df1[attribute_code].unique()     
for feature_name in feature_list:
    for code_num in code_list:
        for month_num in month_list:
            dff2 =  b[(b['month'].isin([str(month_num)])) & (b['year'].isin(['2018'])) & (b['code'].isin([str(code_num)])) & (b['city'].isin([str(feature_name)]))]
            dff2 = dff2.drop(['year'], axis=1)
            dff2 = dff2.rename(columns={'qty': 'qty_2018'})
            dff =  b[(b['month'].isin([str(month_num)])) & (b['year'].isin(['2017'])) & (b['code'].isin([str(code_num)])) & (b['city'].isin([str(feature_name)]))]
            dff = dff.drop(['year'], axis=1)
            dff = dff.rename(columns={'qty': 'qty_2017'})
            dff1 =  b[(b['month'].isin([str(month_num)])) & (b['year'].isin(['2016'])) & (b['code'].isin([str(code_num)])) & (b['city'].isin([str(feature_name)]))]
            dff1 = dff1.drop(['year'], axis=1)
            dff1 = dff1.rename(columns={'qty': 'qty_2016'})
            df2 = dff2.merge(dff, on=['city','code','month'], how='left')
            df3 = df2.merge(dff1,on=['city','code','month'], how='left' )
            result.append(df3)
frame = pd.concat(result) 
frame['year'] = 2018
```

In the same way i wil1 repeat for 2017 and i will get qty_2017 and qty_2016as frame1 and contact both frame and frame1.

The above code gives me the required result but it is very time consuming and not in loop for all years. I need help in what way i can make it better and faster.

Comment: Can you post a copy + paste sample of the dataframe? Than its easier to give you some demo code. In any case, the function use is `shift`:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html